# Compare time in blade using Carbon (Laravel 5.4)

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

In my blade.php file, I try to compare the sign-in time. I want to make a button to send a reminder through email appear if the user for example sign-in after 8:30 am.  But i got a blank error when I try to run my application.

Below is my code

```
@if(Auth::user()->hasRole('Administrator'))
    <td class="td-actions text-right">
        {{$late_time = \Carbon\Carbon::create(2019, 03, 15, 08, 30, 00)->toTimeString()}}
        {{$user_sign_in = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $attendance->sign_in_time)->toTimeString()}}

    @if($user_sign_in->greaterThan($late_time))

        <a class="btn btn-info"  rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-success" data-original-title="" title="Late Notice" href="{{route('attendance.lateattendance',$attendance->user->id)}}">
            <i class="material-icons">assignment_late</i>
            <div class="ripple-container"></div>
        </a>
    @endif
```

Sorry if you don't understand my question. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Why do  you have to do it in blade, why not do it in PHP and set a simple boolean value in blade.  Templates are for presentation, not business logic.  I don't use Laravel but I think they put too many PHP like features in their template engine.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Thank you for your response. I see what your point is :) but I want to know how what I did wrong in my code. I've read the Carbon documentation for time comparison but I'm having a hard time to understand it. I'm new in php and laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@php 

    $late_time = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2019-03-15 08:30:00', 'YourTimeZone');
    $user_sign_in = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $attendance->sign_in_time, 'YourTimeZone');

@endphp
@if($user_sign_in->greaterThan($late_time))

@else

@endif
```

In my case timezone is Asia/Kolkata